# Puppet master executes a catalog on itself

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

Can a puppet master execute its catalog on itself?

I want to automate some tasks on my master server. The best would be to create a node for the master server and apply the catalog directly.

If it's not possible, can I apply the whole catalog manually? If I try to do a manual `puppet apply`, it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master and agent roles of `puppet` are managed by two different processes, so a `puppetmaster` can also have a `puppet` agent running, in which case, the machine will have its catalog served conveniently.

Moreover, it is not at all uncommon to have a set of modules that apply to every host (e.g. a security baseline), including the `puppetmaster`. Of course, you can also have modules that specifically target the `puppetmaster` host.

It is not entirely clear from your question what do you mean by "automate some tasks on my master server": whether you want to keep your `puppetmaster` in a known state or have some arbitrary tasks run on demand.

For the former, the standard behaviour of `puppet` is all you need, for the latter, you could check the `puppet`'s companion project, [Marionette Collective](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/mcollective/).

Comment: I want to keep puppetmaster in a known state ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We actually have a very similar setup where we have a manifest specific to our puppetmasters.

We simply run the puppet agent regularly on them just like we do with any other node.

You just need to make sure to run `puppet agent` instead of `puppet apply` if you want to actually use a catalog known to the puppetmaster process.